# Calling functions asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I want to initiate a Database request, which takes several time and responses with an Integer (`42`).
The `setTimeout` in `dbRequest()` is representative for this request.

The responded integer should be incremented by 1 in the function `initRequest`. Therefore `initRequest` should return `43`.

```
var dbRequest = function () {

  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Hello World! => 42');
    return 42;
  }, 5000);

};

var initRequest = function (cb){
  var test = cb() + 1;
  console.log('Incremented Value: ' + test);
  return test;
};

initRequest(dbRequest);
```

Unfortunately `var test = cb() + 1;` is not waiting for the `setTimeout` and calculates with `NaN`.
The output:

```
Incremented Value: NaN
// 5 sec delay
Hello World! => 42
```

How can I make this function asynchronous, so that `initRequest` waits for `dbRequest` response?

Comment: You seem to have things backwards. The function _is_ asynchronous, that means that it doesn't wait.

Comment: Anything that depends on the result of an asynchronous action has to be done in its callback function. Javascript is single-threaded, it can't stay in the original function and also execute the asynchronous call at the same time.

Comment: Basically the same issue has here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call That question deals with `AJAX` requests instead of `setTimeout`, but it's the same asynchronous issue

Comment: why dont you call the function after 5 seconds on which you will passed 42, and do some action(increment) with this?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly don't know about your case but to get the desire result you could do something like this.

```
var dbRequest = function (callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Hello World! => 42');
        callback(42);
    }, 5000);
};

function initRequest(val){
    var test = val + 1;
    console.log('Incremented Value: ' + test);
}

 dbRequest(initRequest);
```

Call the callback function after particular time, and pass the value with this invoked function for desire action.